# Spatial R - compute density around a point

Tags: r, buffer, spatial

I have a dataset with cities in a French département (more or less a county) and the population in each of the cities. I have another dataset with geographic coordinates of nursing homes in this département.

I would like to compute the population around a radius of 20km of each of my nursing homes.

But the thing is, I do not know how to do that...

Here is the list of the problems I should resolve:

1. Which cities are inside the circle?
2. Which percentage of a city is there in the circle?
3. Under the assumption that the population is homogeneously evenly distributed, how many people are there in the part of city inside the circle?
4. Compute the sum of the population inside the circle

Here is a map of my département, the nursing homes are the points in black.

[image: rhone_pop]

Here is my code (well, it does not work...):

```
library(sf)
# To know which cities are in the circle:
cities_in_circle <- st_intersects(departement, buffer_nh)
```

It gives a list and I do not know how to use it...

To know the area overlapped I should use `st_intersection` and  `st_area` but it does not work with my list above.

Any help would be gladly welcomed!

Comment: Do you need the data ? The thing, the datasets are in sf format, so I do not know how to give it...

Comment: Should this question be asked on GIS StackExchange?